# Put regression summary results in data frame R

Tags: r

I am running several regression models  and desire to have the results in a data frame. I tried several methods they have been unsuccessful.

```
# Generate some fake data: three responses and eight covariates 
df <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(50), y2 = rnorm(50), y3 = rnorm(50), 
                 aa = rnorm(50), ab = rnorm(50), ca = rnorm(50), 
                 cd = rpois(50, 30), v8 = runif(50)) 

# Create a vector of covariate names 
xs <- c("aa","ab", "ca","cd","v8") 
# Initialize a list whose length is that of the vector xs 
rl1 <- vector('list', 5) 
rl2 <- vector('list', 5) 
rl3 <- vector('list', 5) 

for(i in 1:5) { fm1<- as.formula(paste('y1', xs[i], sep = '~')) 
fm2 <- as.formula(paste('y2', xs[i], sep = '~')) 
fm3 <- as.formula(paste('y3', xs[i], sep = '~')) 
rl1[[i]] <- summary(lm(fm1, data = df) )
rl2[[i]] <- summary(lm(fm2, data = df) )
rl3[[i]] <- summary(lm(fm3, data = df) )
} 

rl1
rl2

###
#The goal is to:
#create a data frame for results that looks like this 

Variable    t value     Pr(>|t|)        
aa      -1.032      0.3070 
ab      -0.121      0.9043
ca       0.041      0.967
cd       0.429      0.670
v8      -1.204      0.2346 

and create a data frame for results that looks like this 
Variable    rl1.t value r2.t value  
aa      -1.032      -1.846 
ab      -0.121      -0.230
ca       0.041      1.347
cd       0.429      0.211
v8      -1.204      0.214
```

Lastly I came across this code to run the regression in this fashion and I want to give credit  and say thanks, although I don't recall the source.

Comment: Check out the `tidy` function from the `broom` package.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention uses many packages (`dplyr`, `tidyr`, `purrr` and `broom`).  All are conveniently located in the `tidyverse` meta-package, which helps install all of these packages.

The `tidyverse` package has a workflow based around tidy data and tidy data tools.  You can read more about it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/vignettes/manifesto.html).

Your example, using the `tidyverse` packages is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom) # is part of the tidyverse but has to be attached on its own.

df <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(50), y2 = rnorm(50), y3 = rnorm(50), 
                 aa = rnorm(50), ab = rnorm(50), ca = rnorm(50), 
                 cd = rpois(50, 30), v8 = runif(50)) 

xs <- c("aa","ab", "ca","cd","v8") 

results <- tibble(covariates = xs, data = list(df)) %>% 
       mutate(fm1 = map2(data, covariates, ~lm(as.formula(paste('y1', .y, sep = '~')),data = .x)), 
              fm2 = map2(data, covariates, ~lm(as.formula(paste('y2', .y, sep = '~')),data = .x)),
              fm3 = map2(data, covariates, ~lm(as.formula(paste('y3', .y, sep = '~')),data = .x))) %>% 
       gather(model, result, fm1:fm3) %>% 
       mutate(stats = map(result, tidy)) 


results %>% 
  select(-data, -result) %>% 
  spread(model, stats) %>% 
  unnest(.sep = "_")

# A tibble: 10 × 16
   covariates    fm1_term fm1_estimate fm1_std.error fm1_statistic fm1_p.value    fm2_term fm2_estimate
        <chr>       <chr>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <chr>        <dbl>
1          aa (Intercept)  0.186250282    0.10901934     1.7084150  0.09401936 (Intercept)  -0.13702761
2          aa          aa -0.122391949    0.09736266    -1.2570727  0.21480983          aa   0.07086972
3          ab (Intercept)  0.235819869    0.11000625     2.1436951  0.03715205 (Intercept)  -0.07707552
4          ab          ab  0.210060898    0.11165387     1.8813580  0.06599560          ab   0.26121398
5          ca (Intercept)  0.192849006    0.11315134     1.7043458  0.09478244 (Intercept)  -0.13487163
6          ca          ca  0.028244577    0.11597189     0.2435467  0.80861978          ca   0.01340660
7          cd (Intercept)  0.336090343    0.67322033     0.4992279  0.61989940 (Intercept)  -1.50990351
8          cd          cd -0.004866459    0.02170098    -0.2242506  0.82351414          cd   0.04484769
9          v8 (Intercept)  0.037664728    0.18697545     0.2014421  0.84120415 (Intercept)   0.12866580
10         v8          v8  0.353757262    0.35827371     0.9873939  0.32840091          v8  -0.62992103
# ... with 8 more variables: fm2_std.error <dbl>, fm2_statistic <dbl>, fm2_p.value <dbl>, fm3_term <chr>,
#   fm3_estimate <dbl>, fm3_std.error <dbl>, fm3_statistic <dbl>, fm3_p.value <dbl>
```

In this example the steps look like:

1. Create a tibble of your covariate names and nest the data for each covariate.
2. Create your models fm1 to fm3 for each covariate, as separate list-columns, mapping a linear model to each piece.
3. Reshape that into long format (key-value pairs)
4. Create a stats column, and tidy that by mapping `broom::tidy` to the result column.
5. Store that whole thing in a tibble

Then you can use the `results` tibble to get what you need using `unnest` and manipulate it into what you want via `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Comment: I copied and paste the code as provided and the result differ from what you posted, in short it did not work on my end. Moreover when I attempt run the code on my data it cause r to have a fatal run time error and terminate the session.  Any new ideas would greatly valued. Thanks

Comment: The results will differ as you're using random variables, and I didn't use `set.seed()` prior to my analysis.  As to your fatal error, I can't diagnose or debug problems in your own data.  You should work through the code step by step, find the error and try to correct the problem.